# Classification/Prediction in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I have a corpus of **N** documents classified as *spam* / *no-spam*. I am following the standard procedure to pre-process the data in R([code here](https://gist.github.com/elyase/5365552)). The pre-processing ends with a `DocumenTermMatrix` using weights as **tfidf**.

Now I want to classify new documents with my model.

How can I calculate the corresponding `DocumentVector` (using the **tf** of the document and the **idfs** of the corpus) for a single new document? I would like to avoid recalculating the `DocumentTermMatrix` for the whole corpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and this functionality is not included in the tm package. Ingo Feinerer suggested to build a function to get the DocumentVector. The function would need to use the previously built tm or dtm from the corpus and the new document. First pre-process the new document in the same way done for the corpus and create a list with the words and tf. You can merge the words from the tm/dtm (ex. tdm$dimnames$Terms) in the way that your new document is transformed to have the same Terms of your corpus with the tf values of the document (simple merging). Then divide the tf by the idfs of the corpus in the standard way:

```
cs<-row_sums(tm>0)
 lnrs<-log2(nDocs(tm)/cs)
 tf*lnrs  #
```

finish returning your DocumentVector. 
 You can then use vector as a data.frame when predicting with the SVM directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what svm library you use, but it seems that your SVM model is stored in `Corpus.svm`  -- correct?

For prediction of a new document you can follow procedure described at: http://planatscher.net/svmtut/svmtut.html task 2. If you use some other library the procedure will be similar. There is also practical example with IRIS dataset. The only difference is that your new document has to be processed in the same way as training examples (i.e. remove stopwords, tf-idf,...)

Comment: The question actually has to do with you last sentence "The only difference is that your new document has to be processed in the same way as training examples (i.e. remove stopwords, tf-idf,...)". How to get this DocumentVector? The model used is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: during testing - you use values for idf from training corpora and tf depends only on test article. More practically:http://bostondecision.com/2012/05/16/how-to-build-a-text-mining-machine-learning-document-classification-system-in-r/, http://web.letras.up.pt/bhsmaia/EDV/apresentacoes/Bradzil_Classif_withTM.pdf or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14219/how-well-does-r-scale-to-text-classification-tasks